# Create ListPopUpWindow as designed by Material in Android

Tags: android, material-design

I'm trying to create a select menu in Android instead of using Spinner, but i'm facing some problems with the layout. How can I create something like the image below using ListPopUpWindow?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Use PopupWindow with a custom layout of your choice. In your case ListView or RecyclerView. showAtLocation or showAsDropDown are used to pin popupWindow location. Here is a cool example http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/02/android-popupwindow-show-as-dropdown.html

Comment: Thanks, it helped me. I'll try to implement.

Answer (score 1):

I really like these menus floating over selected items, so I created my own DropDown class which implements your case. It does pretty much what @uguboz wrote.

I'm using PopupWindow with a custom layout with a RecyclerView. Then I handle onClick, display that window and use overriden PopupWindow.update() to calculate correct window position.

The most interesting part would be this code:

```
public class DropDownMenu extends PopupWindow {

    public boolean show(View anchor) {
        mAnchorView = anchor;

        super.showAtLocation(anchor, Gravity.START | Gravity.TOP, 0, 0);

        update();

        return true;
    }

    public void update() {
        final Resources res = getContentView().getContext().getResources();

        int margin = (int) res.getDimension(R.dimen.carbon_margin);
        int itemHeight = (int) res.getDimension(R.dimen.carbon_listItemHeight);
        int marginHalf = (int) res.getDimension(R.dimen.carbon_paddingHalf);

        ArrayAdapter adapter = getAdapter();

        Rect windowRect = new Rect();
        mAnchorView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(windowRect);
        int hWindow = windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top;
        int wWindow = windowRect.right - windowRect.left;

        int[] location = new int[2];
        mAnchorView.getLocationInWindow(location);

        if (mode == DropDown.Mode.Over) {
            int maxHeightAbove = location[1] - windowRect.top - marginHalf * 2;
            int maxItemsAbove = maxHeightAbove / itemHeight;
            int maxHeightBelow = hWindow - location[1] - marginHalf * 2;
            int maxItemsBelow = maxHeightBelow / itemHeight;

            int itemsBelow = Math.min(adapter.getItemCount() - selectedItem, maxItemsBelow);
            int itemsAbove = Math.min(selectedItem, maxItemsAbove);

            int popupX = location[0] - margin - marginHalf;
            int popupY = location[1] - marginHalf * 2 - itemsAbove * itemHeight - (itemHeight - (mAnchorView.getHeight() - mAnchorView.getPaddingTop() -
                    mAnchorView.getPaddingBottom())) / 2 + mAnchorView.getPaddingTop();
            int popupWidth = mAnchorView.getWidth() + margin * 2 + marginHalf * 2 - mAnchorView.getPaddingLeft() - mAnchorView.getPaddingRight();
            int popupHeight = marginHalf * 4 + Math.max(1, itemsAbove + itemsBelow) * itemHeight;

            popupWidth = Math.min(popupWidth, wWindow - marginHalf * 2);
            popupX = Math.max(popupX, 0);
            popupX = Math.min(popupX, wWindow - popupWidth);

            LinearLayoutManager manager = (LinearLayoutManager) recycler.getLayoutManager();
            manager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(selectedItem - itemsAbove, 0);

            update(popupX, popupY, popupWidth, popupHeight);
        } else {
            // not interesting
        }

        super.update();
    }
}
```

The code is way too long to paste it here with all details, so I'll serve you a link to the class: [DropDownMenu](https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon/blob/master/carbon/src/main/java/carbon/internal/DropDownMenu.java). Use it as you wish. I hope you'll find the code useful.

And I've made a sample for that image from the guidelines. It can be found in the sample app under Guidelines -> Menus/Behavior

[image]
[image]

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of code, btw I think it's going to be very useful :D. Thank you so much

Comment: Is there any tutorial to teach how to import and use your project? I'm facing some problems to execute SampleActivity, for example, cannot find implementations on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.<a href="openAndroidSdkManager">Open Android SDK Manager</a>. This repository is already installed.

Comment: No. The project is supposed to be used as a Maven dependency (the libraries) or as an apk (the sample app). Your case is a bit different and I don't have anything ready for you. I suppose that your issue might be related to Android Studio version. The most recent code was developed using AS 3.0 canary 5 with gradle 4.1 m1. If you have more questions or need help, you can ask them in Carbon's community (https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/111973718340428039040). In case of issues with code, feel free to raise an issue (https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon/issues)